Is there a way to easily add new lines in an contenteditable div?
I am building a texteditor and using a contenteditable div for it.
It all works peachy except when I want to lower a line of text by hitting return at the start of the row.
In my app I color code the text based on the character used at the beginning of the row. And one such type of text is simple bodytext, which can be hidden by pressing a toggle. The text then is replaced by a placeholder showing the wordcount of the hidden text.
Now in this hidden state when I want to lower this placeholder by putting the caret at the beginning of the row and hitting return the placeholder no longer keeps the required placeholder class for it to be recognized as a placeholder.
What then happens is when I want to show the text again, the placeholder is not getting replaced with the hidden text, but instead the placeholder text itself overwrites the originally hidden text.
function handleInput(event) {
    const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!selection.rangeCount) return;  // No selection available.

    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let node = selection.anchorNode;  // Get the node where the caret is.
    let div = node.nodeType === 3 ? node.parentNode : node;  // Get the closest div parent or the node itself.

    if (div === event.target) {  // If the node is the editor, create a new div.
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'bodytext'; // Default to bodytext for new divs
        editor.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(node);
    } else if (div.tagName !== 'DIV') {
        // If the parent is not a div, wrap the node in a new div.
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'bodytext'; // Default to bodytext for new divs
        node.before(newDiv);
        newDiv.appendChild(node);
        div = newDiv;
    }

    // Handling new lines after a placeholder-container specifically
    if (node === editor && div.previousElementSibling && div.previousElementSibling.classList.contains('placeholder-container')) {
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'bodytext';
        editor.insertBefore(newDiv, div.previousElementSibling.nextSibling);
        moveCursorToDiv(newDiv);
        return;  // Prevent further processing
    }

    // Apply class based on the content starting character or its absence.
    if (node.textContent.trim() === '') {
        div.className = 'empty'; // Handle empty divs specially if needed
    } else if (node.textContent.startsWith('#')) {
        div.className = 'heading';
    } else if (node.textContent.startsWith('=')) {
        div.className = 'synopsis';
    } else if (node.textContent.startsWith('@')) {
        div.className = 'non-narrative';
    } else {
        div.className = 'bodytext';
    }

    moveCursorToDiv(div);  // Move the cursor to the end of the new or updated div
}

function moveCursorToDiv(div) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    range.selectNodeContents(div);  
    range.collapse(false);  
    selection.removeAllRanges();  
    selection.addRange(range);
}

All I want to do is to be able to lower a line of placeholder and have it keep the class it had.
It works with all other classes that I have used, except for my placeholder-container class, which gets overwritten by the bodytext class.
I tried just forcing new lines of <div class="empty"><br></div> whenever a new line is created, but it then creates 2 lines always one that just is bodytext and the other an empty empty-div which brings with it other problems.

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Why use a contenteditable div instead of a textarea?

I recomend to more efficiently just use a Textarea and style it to look like any div you like.
